# How to remove cloudfront from a wordpress site on aws instance?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, w3-total-cache

I have installed a wordpress site using bitnami on aws instance. After I added cloudfront on aws instance and integrated with w3 total cache.

The problem is, when I change any files like css or js via ftp or wordpress theme editor, it doesn't make any change to my site. Its still loading the cloudfront cached version.

Is there a way to force clear cloudfront cache? Also users browser cache?
What I think I better remove the cloudfront from my site for now? Which one is best and easy option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the expiration time for CloudFront.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#expiration-individual-objects

Also, it would be better to omit CloudFront until your site design is complete.

Once you have deployed a production site, you can manually invalidate individual objects:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Be aware that this will incur a fee once you invalidate more than 1k objects in a month.

Comment: As I already added cloudfront, how can I remove cloudfront from my wordpress website and aws instance?

Comment: @FoisalMehedi Remove CDN redirection from httpd.conf file.

Comment: @mcfinnigan I made a mistake during disabling the distribution. I deleted that distribution without creating an invalidation, also I removed the configuration from w3 total cache cdn settings. Still my site is loading contents from the distribution. What Can I do?

Comment: @mcfinnigan Now I have disabled the cdn from w3 total cache and Now my site is loading from its origin. I think the problem is solved for now. Thank you for your nice support.